# Conditional Operator inside the tool tip is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I have done a tooltip with angular material. Conditional evaluation is not working.

The following is the code

```
<li [ngClass]="{'active': selectedPage === pages[1]}">
<a class="dot"  matTooltip="{{selectedPage == pages[4] ? User Name: ${userInputForm.value.newUserName} : ''}}" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="tooltipFont"></a></li>
```

**Expected output:**

User Name: Sam

Or

User Name: ' '

But the output is printed as string inside the double quotes. How can I make my code to get the correct output?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `User Name:` is common, separate it out and then append rest part with conditional operator within a bracket `(selectedPage == pages[4] ?  userInputForm.value.newUserName : '')`.

Try like this:

```
<a class="dot"  [matTooltip]="'User Name:' +  (selectedPage == pages[4] ?  userInputForm.value.newUserName : '')" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="tooltipFont"></a>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcannu?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-overview-example.html)**

Comment: This will not work, you are using `:` twice in conditional statement, which assume it as seprator.

Comment: But the second one is added within `' '`

Comment: Yeah... Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this -

```
<a [matTooltip]="selectedPage == pages[4] ? 'User Name:' + userInputForm?.value?.newUserName : 'User name: -'" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="tooltipFont"></a></li>
```

Bonus Tip - Binding is always preferred to be a `[]` instead of `{{}}` wherever possible, as this will make your template more cleaner in readability point of view.